# Node.js unit test case using mocha

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, chai, node-modules

I have a `myfunctions.js` file which has function

```
function lineObject(year, arrest, primary_Type, Description){
  this.year = year;
  this.arrest = arrest;
  this.primary_Type = primary_Type;
  this.Description = Description;
}

module.exports={
   lineObj : lineObject()
};
```

and my test case is something like bellow

```
    var chai = require('chai');
    var expect = chai.expect;
    const myfunction = require("../myfunctions");
    const lineObject = myfunction.lineObj;
    describe("Test suit", function(err) {
it("Test the fulsh option", function() {
     
  var retobj= lineObject('2017','yes','yes','tes');

       expect(retobj).to.have.property('year');
    });
});
```

But when i run my test it throws and error `TypeError: lineObject is not a function`

Any suggestions please

Comment: Are you using `module.export` in myfunctions.js to export the module?

Comment: I have updated the post.. i am using `modile.export`

Comment: You're not exporting a function. You are exporting the result of calling `lineObject()`, which is `undefined`. This is just a typo. Please delete your question as questions that are due to problems that are only caused by typos are subject to closure and deletion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't propertly exporting your `lineObj` function, you're *invoking* it and assigning the result (which would be `undefined`) to the `lineObj` property.

You can fix by assigning the function itself

```
module.exports = {
    lineObj: lineObject
}
```

Looking further at your code, you seem to expect `lineObj()` to give you something back which, based on your current implementation, won't. You would need to actually *return* something for that to work e.g.

```
function lineObject() {
    return {
       ...
    };
}
```

Based on how your exporting, you could get away with `return this` which would give you a reference to the object your exporting back (common chaining pattern)...but I doubt this is really what you are trying to do.